# How to control NSTextField is editable in NSTableView(view-based)

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I try to implement delegate method
 - (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView shouldEditTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
But it never get called.

I also try to implement another method

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

    NSTableCellView *cellView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:[tableColumn identifier] owner:self];
    NSTextField *textField = [cellView textField];
    [textField setEditable:NO or YES];
    return cellView;
}
```

But it doesn't work

Anyone can give me an advance about control editable of NSTextFile in NSTableView.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you hooked up the delegate and made sure in the debugger the table view at runtime actually has a valid reference to its delegate?

Comment: Yes, because the - (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row method works very well.